# Error: channel gmail-sent: slave sent cannot be opened

Tags: email, gmail-imap, mbsync

I'm able to sync my Gmail inbox, but the sent folder does not work.

This is my **.mbsyncrc**

```
IMAPStore martinstabenfeldt-remote
    Account martinstabenfeldt

MaildirStore martinstabenfeldt-local
    Path ~/.mail/martinstabenfeldt/           
    INBOX ~/.mail/martinstabenfeldt/INBOX

Channel martinstabenfeldt
    Master :martinstabenfeldt-remote:
    Slave :martinstabenfeldt-local:
    Patterns *
    # Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
    Create Both
    # Save the synchronization state files in the relevant directory
    SyncState *

Channel martinstabenfeldt-inbox
    Master ":martinstabenfeldt-remote:INBOX"
    Slave  ":martinstabenfeldt-local:INBOX"

Channel martinstabenfeldt-sent
    Master ":martinstabenfeldt-remote:[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
    Slave  ":martinstabenfeldt-local:sent"
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ mbsync --verbose  martinstabenfeldt-sent
Logging in...
Opening master box [Gmail]/Sent Mail...
Opening slave box sent...
Error: channel martinstabenfeldt-sent: slave sent cannot be opened.
C: 1/1  B: 1/1  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
```

Any idea why this fails?
I've created the **~/.mail/martinstabenfeldt/sent** folder. And this folder is empty.

Comment: Have a look at https://delog.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/access-imap-server-from-the-command-line-using-openssl/ and tell us what the IMAP server returns when executing `tag LIST "" "*"`

Answer (score 13):

Not the OP's case, but you can get this exact error message if you forgot the trailing slash in the `Path` configuration variable for the `MaildirStore`.

The man page does say the trailing slash is needed, but that's easy to overlook.

Comment: i wasted too much time figuring this out. I added a trailing / to the path and not the inbox! derp! thanks man!

Comment: Ah I also wasted way too much time until I saw this too. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, you saved me! wish the application did that by itself tbh.

Answer (score 6):

Try Using [Google Mail] instead of [Gmail]. It should work.
I believe there is Starred, Spam, Sent Mail, Important, Drafts, Bin and All Mail  that will work with [Google Mail]/.

Here is my config file:

```
IMAPAccount gmail
Host imap.gmail.com
User <your email address>
Pass <your password>
SSLType IMAPS
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

IMAPStore gmail-remote
Account gmail

MaildirStore gmail-local
Path ~/mail/gmail/
Inbox ~/mail/gmail/inbox

Channel gmail-default
Master :gmail-remote:
Slave  :gmail-local:
Patterns INBOX

Channel gmail-sent
Master ":gmail-remote:[Google Mail]/Sent Mail"
slave  :gmail-local:sent

Channel gmail-trash
Master :gmail-remote:"[Google Mail]/Bin"
slave  :gmail-local:trash

Channel gmail-archive
Master :gmail-remote:"[Google Mail]/All Mail"
slave  :gmail-local:all

Channel gmail-drafts
Master :gmail-remote:"[Google Mail]/Drafts"
Slave :gmail-local:drafts

# Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
Create slave # Only create locally for now
SyncState *

Group gmail
Channel gmail-default
Channel gmail-trash
Channel gmail-archive
Channel gmail-sent
Channel gmail-drafts
```

If you still have issues you could try the following config:

```
IMAPAccount gmail
Host imap.gmail.com
User <your email address>
Pass <your password>
SSLType IMAPS
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

IMAPStore gmail-remote
Account gmail

MaildirStore gmail-local
Path ~/mail/gmail/
Inbox ~/mail/gmail/inbox

Channel gmail-default
Master :gmail-remote:
Slave  :gmail-local:
Patterns "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"

# Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
Create slave # Only create locally for now
SyncState *

Group gmail
Channel gmail-default
```

Once you have this run the following command:
mbsync -Dmn gmail

You should see some output:

```
* NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
4 OK Success
>>> 5 LIST "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Notes"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Personal"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Receipts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Unwanted"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Work"
* LIST (\HasChildren \Noselect) "/" "[Google Mail]"
* LIST (\All \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Google Mail]/All Mail"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "/" "[Google Mail]/Bin"
* LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Google Mail]/Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Important) "/" "[Google Mail]/Important"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "[Google Mail]/Sent Mail"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Junk) "/" "[Google Mail]/Spam"
* LIST (\Flagged \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Google Mail]/Starred"
5 OK Success
>>> 6 LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT Requested
6 OK 73 good day (Success)
```

From here you can see what your respective remote folder names should  be.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12143747)

Comment: I had the same issue just a day or two ago. Using [Gmail]/Sent Mail did not work. Switching to [Google Mail]/Sent Mail worked for me. So I'm not sure how else one can answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed but that gave me this error: `Error: channel martinstabenfeldt-sent: both master [Google Mail]/Sent Mail and slave sent cannot be opened.`

Comment: Can you post your complete *.mbsyncrc* ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by your quotes; instead of:

```
Channel martinstabenfeldt-sent
    Master ":martinstabenfeldt-remote:[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
    Slave  ":martinstabenfeldt-local:sent"
```

try:

```
Channel martinstabenfeldt-sent
    Master :martinstabenfeldt-remote:"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
    Slave  :martinstabenfeldt-local:sent
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it does not change the error: > 
*Error: channel martinstabenfeldt-sent: both master [Gmail]/Sent Mail and slave sent cannot be opened.*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Channel gmail-sent
Far:gmail-remote:"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
Near:gmail-locat:"Sent"
CopyArrivalDate yes
Create Both
Expunge Both
SyncState *
```

add the channel to Group

```
Group gmail
Channel <other_channels>
Channel gmail-sent
```